# Pandas | How to calculate the average value of each cell in multiple dataframe with the same shape?

Tags: pandas

I have several DataFrames like this:

[image]

they are saving in a list df_list = [df1,df2,df3,df4,df5....]

I want to generate a new DataFrame `df_average`.

In `df_average`,  each grid is equal to the average values of the corresponding grid of `df1`, `df2`, `df3`, `df4`,`df4`. For example:

```
df_average[1,'Q1'] = average(df1[1,'Q1'],df2[1,'Q1'],df3[1,'Q1'],df4[1,'Q1']),
df_average[1,'Q2'] = average(df1[1,'Q2'],df2[1,'Q2'],df3[1,'Q2'],df4[1,'Q2'])
```

How to realize it in an efficient way ?

Comment: Nilesh and I would love some upvotes and a mark as accepted answer if we solved your problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use pd.concat, followed by a groupby on the index using mean for aggregation.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Q1':[1,2,3], 'Q2':[1,7,8], 'Q3':[8,9,1], 'Q4':[4,3,7]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Q1':[7,9,10], 'Q2':[9,2,8], 'Q3':[3,4,2], 'Q4':[1,5,6]})
df_average = pd.concat([df1, df2])
df_average = df_average.groupby(df_average.index).agg({'Q1': 'mean',
                                                       'Q2': 'mean',
                                                       'Q3': 'mean',
                                                       'Q4': 'mean'})

print(df_average)

    Q1  Q2  Q3  Q4
0   4.0 5.0 5.5 2.5
1   5.5 4.5 6.5 4.0
2   6.5 8.0 1.5 6.5
```

Answer (score 2):

Code below averages values for each cell. The output size is same as the other dataframes:

```
# Import libraries
import pandas as pd

# Create DataFrame
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Q1': [1,2,3],
    'Q2': [11,12,13],
    'Q3': [10,20,30],
    'Q4': [31,32,33],
    'Q5': [61,62,63],
})
df2 = df1.copy()*2
df3 = df1.copy()*0.5
df4 = df1.copy()*-1

# Get average
df_average = (df1+df2+df3+df4)/4
df_average
```

Output:

```
      Q1     Q2     Q3      Q4      Q5
0  0.625  6.875   6.25  19.375  38.125
1  1.250  7.500  12.50  20.000  38.750
2  1.875  8.125  18.75  20.625  39.375
```